# sports-reference.com legality of using their data for other applications

Tags: sports, legal

I am interested in using [sports-reference](http://www.sports-reference.com/)'s data for web modelling and a web application. I was checking the [TOS](http://www.sports-reference.com/termsofuse.shtml) of sports-reference and I can't quite grasp the main idea about the legality of using their data for other applications. Does anybody here have experience with sports-reference data and it's legality of use. Is it fine for me to use their data freely or do I need to get a license from SRL?

Comment: You might ask for an interpretation of the TOS at http://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Question does little more than promote a low-quality network of sites full of advertising.

Comment: @Skram I find the licensing discussion relevant to this forum since this is what make data open

Comment: just in FYI I'm not promoting this site nor I'm related to the site in any way. I'm only interested in using the data and knowing about the legal implications.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions on the interpretation of TOS do not belong here, maybe you can ask them on the law stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TOS are quite explicit you can't use their data without their consent and buy having a license.

`Any use, reproduction, or distribution of this Site or Content without SRL's advance written consent is prohibited, except, however, you may download one copy of these materials, and you may print one copy of these materials for your use in learning about, evaluating, or acquiring SRL's or its licensees' or licensors' services or products, provided that you include a complete copy of this entire page.`

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right. The part were they forbid the use of data seems to be supported by numeral 5. which states: "The information on this Site is for informational purposes only." What confused me was that all the data is made available in .csv and the fact that there is nowhere you can buy a license or buy a subscription of the data.

Comment: I didn't look on how to get a license. Best way will be to contact them directly.